# How to find whether the ATM Display is Touch Screen or not using XFS?

Tags: cen-xfs

I want to find out what type of display does a ATM have; touch screen or not? Is this possible to find out using CEN XFS? I read the manual and couldn't find any Service Class specific to display. Is there one or have I missed it? Can someone point this out please? Thank you very much.

Comment: No, there is nothing in the specification regarding screen type installed. It would have to be something you set up by yourself in your application. Or try to ask the PIN Capabilities, and suppose that if there is no function keys available, you probably have a touch screen. Make test in different models to know if it is true. It is only an idea...

Comment: Thanks @SuperG280 for the clarification.